How to use AWS SDK for Dynamodb in an android application, not using Amplify
I've run into a bit of a brick wall when trying to figure out the AWS SDK with Dynamodb.
I have an android app that I want to use to access a DynamoDB table.
what I'm trying to set up is:
an IAM role with correct permissions, which will use Cognito for guest access.
A DynamoDB table.
I'm using Kotlin.
I'm not using Amplify (I'm not opposed to using it, I've just been looking for the easiest way to achieve this and don't know much about it yet).
my main problem is that the
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.(X)

never works, no matter how much googling dependency issues and AWS SDK I do (which is hours at this point)

You should expand on why no Amplify. Note that Android != Linux and Android != JavaSE so any library SDK may have missing dependencies in the Android environment. Also if the SDK is using JDBC under the hood, please read: JDBC vs Web Service for Android

@MorrisonChang I'm not opposed to using Amplify, I just don't know a lot about it yet! I was looking to use the least amount of things possible, and I'm still figuring out what that looks like

Can you share your build file?

See my comment below. Use the AWS SDK for Kotlin -- not the Java V1 or V2 SDK.

To access Amazon DynamoDB (or other AWS Services) on an Android app using Kotlin, look at using the AWS SDK for Kotlin. See the docs here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-kotlin/latest/developer-guide/setup.html
You are trying to use Java V1 to build an Android app. V1 packages always start with com.amazonaws.services.
This is a poor practice. For starters,  the V1 SDK is on the Path to deprecation.
The AWS SDK for Kotlin (unlike the Java V1 or V2 SDK) supports full Kotlin features such as Coroutines.
You can use this SDK to invoke DynamoDB operations by using this Kotlin Service Client:
aws.sdk.kotlin.services.dynamodb.DynamoDbClient 

You can find DynamoDB examples in the same dev guide:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-kotlin/latest/developer-guide/kotlin_dynamodb_code_examples.html
For example - to put music data into a DyanamoDB table, use this code
import aws.sdk.kotlin.services.dynamodb.DynamoDbClient
import aws.sdk.kotlin.services.dynamodb.model.AttributeValue
import aws.sdk.kotlin.services.dynamodb.model.PutItemRequest
import kotlin.system.exitProcess
// snippet-end:[dynamodb.kotlin.put_item.import]

/**
Before running this Kotlin code example, set up your development environment,
including your credentials.

For more information, see the following documentation topic:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-kotlin/latest/developer-guide/setup.html
*/

suspend fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val usage = """
        Usage:
            <tableName> <key> <keyVal> <albumtitle> <albumtitleval> <awards> <awardsval> <Songtitle> <songtitleval>

        Where:
            tableName - The Amazon DynamoDB table in which an item is placed (for example, Music3).
            key - The key used in the Amazon DynamoDB table (for example, Artist).
            keyval - The key value that represents the item to get (for example, Famous Band).
            albumTitle - The album title (for example, AlbumTitle).
            AlbumTitleValue - The name of the album (for example, Songs About Life).
            Awards - The awards column (for example, Awards).
            AwardVal - The value of the awards (for example, 10).
            SongTitle - The song title (for example, SongTitle).
            SongTitleVal - The value of the song title (for example, Happy Day).
            """"

    if (args.size != 9) {
        println(usage)
        exitProcess(0)
    }

    val tableName = args[0]
    val key = args[1]
    val keyVal = args[2]
    val albumTitle = args[3]
    val albumTitleValue = args[4]
    val awards = args[5]
    val awardVal = args[6]
    val songTitle = args[7]
    val songTitleVal = args[8]

    putItemInTable(tableName, key, keyVal, albumTitle, albumTitleValue, awards, awardVal, songTitle, songTitleVal)
}

// snippet-start:[dynamodb.kotlin.put_item.main]
suspend fun putItemInTable(
    tableNameVal: String,
    key: String,
    keyVal: String,
    albumTitle: String,
    albumTitleValue: String,
    awards: String,
    awardVal: String,
    songTitle: String,
    songTitleVal: String,
) {
    val itemValues = mutableMapOf<String, AttributeValue>()

    // Add all content to the table.
    itemValues[key] = AttributeValue.S(keyVal)
    itemValues[songTitle] = AttributeValue.S(songTitleVal)
    itemValues[albumTitle] = AttributeValue.S(albumTitleValue)
    itemValues[awards] = AttributeValue.S(awardVal)

    val request =
        PutItemRequest {
            tableName = tableNameVal
            item = itemValues
        }

    DynamoDbClient { region = "us-east-1" }.use { ddb ->
        ddb.putItem(request)
        println(" A new item was placed into $tableNameVal.")
    }
}

